# Change image based on browser

Tags: jquery, image, browser, cross-browser

I need to be able to change an image depending on the browser being used.

I.e, if it's Chrome, it will show Image X, if Firefox, it will show Image Z, if IE, it will show Image Y

I'm guessing I will have to use jQuery.browser, but not sure how to take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) is dropped from jQuery 1.9 you have to include [jQuery-Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme)

However You could also do it using `navigator.userAgent`

```
var x = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();  

if(x.indexOf("chrome") > -1 ) alert("chrome")
else if(x.indexOf("firefox") > -1 ) alert("firefox");
else if(x.indexOf("msie") > -1 ) alert("ie");
```

However IE 11 userAgent says

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Yes. IE 11 doesnt say it is IE anymore, it says it is Mozilla.

Although, all IE versions respond the word Trident (its layout engine) in all of its versions.

So something like this could work in your javascript

```
if(x.indexOf("trident") > -1 ) alert("ie");
```

**Alternate**

```
 var x = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();   
 var browser = x.match(/chrome|msie|firefox|trident/));
 alert(browser) // example chrome, firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $.browser.mozilla )
{
    alert( "I just found Mozilla w00T" );
}
```

If you're using jQuery 1.9+ you will need [jQuery-Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme)

Instead of alert you simply switch pictures.